# Getting function "gen_random_uuid" already exists with same argument types while creating pgcrypto extension in pg_catalog schema

Tags: postgresql

My organization is trying to migrate from Postgres10 to Postgres14 and so we are trying to create pgcrypto extension in PG14 under pg_catalog schema so that its available for all schemas, but getting the below error while creating pgcrypto in pg_catalog schema,

function "gen_random_uuid" already exists with same argument types

can somebody explain me the root cause of this error and help me to solve this issue.I have

[Postgres14 Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwCVL.png)

Comment: you don't need the pg_crypto extension any more in Postgres 14. It now has a built-in `gen_random_uuid()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html - and you should never create extensions in the `pg_catalog` schema - that's the reason why you get the error in the first place.

Comment: can you tell me if gen_random_uuid() and pg_crypto are the same?,because as checked the docs pg_crypto provides the below functionality,1. General Hashing Functions 2.Password Hashing Functions 3. PGP Encryption Functions 4. Raw Encryption Functions 5. Random-Data Functions.but gen_random_uuid provides only random uuid generation and also can you elaborate on why the extensions should not be created in pg_catalog

Comment: our functionality is to use pgp_sym_encrypt and pgp_sym_decrypt, this cant be used using gen_random_uuid and so we are creating pgcrypto extension in pg_catalog schema  since we have multiple schemas done with sharding.So is there any way to create pgcrypto globally so all the schemas can use it.@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I had to execute `START TRANSACTION ; DROP FUNCTION public.gen_random_uuid; CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto; COMMIT;` to deal with `ERROR:  function "gen_random_uuid" already exists with same argument types`

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, create an extension or anything else in the system schema `pg_catalog`.  That's what the `public` schema is good for.

The immediate cause of the error is that there is already a system function with this name.

Comment: but the extensions created in public schema cannot be accessed in other schemas right,that is why i wanted to create the extension in pg_catalog so that it has global access. can you elaborate on why extensions should not be created in pg_catalog.

Comment: Simply put `public` into `search_path`.